# Error: `path` must be a string

Tags: r

Olá!!! Estou aprendendo R pois preciso fazer dois trabalhos com estatística.
Estou tentando criar um Loop, mas recebo a mensagem de erro " 'path' must be a string. Essa é a sequencia de comandos...

```
leitura_arquivos_csv <- list.files(path= "D:/MESTRADO/DADOS ILHABELA/DADOS ILHABELA/Trabalho CH - ilhabela presal/bases_orig_finbra_ilha/", all.files = FALSE)
#
#Definindo agora um vetor com o nome dos arquivos "nomes_arquivos" que vai excluir a terminação "csv" 
nomes_arquivos <- substr(leitura_arquivos_csv,8,21)

#fazendo o Loop com todos os arquivos
quantidade_arq <-length(leitura_arquivos_csv)
local_gravação <- "D:/MESTRADO/DADOS ILHABELA/DADOS ILHABELA/Trabalho CH - ilhabela presal/bases_orig_finbra_ilha/"
for(i in 1:quantidade_arq){assign(nomes_arquivos[i],read_xlsx(paste(local_gravação,leitura_arquivos_csv, sep ="" )))}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O principal erro é tentar fazer tudo na mesma instrução.
Dentro do ciclo `for` o `assign` deve ser dividido em cada uma das instruções que contém. Assim é possível ver que falta indexar `leitura_arquivos_csv`, em cada iteração está a criar com o `paste` um vetor de nomes.

```
#
# Definir uma vez "local_gravação" e usá-la sempre 
# que for preciso. Não tem a barra final para mais
# tarde poder usar a função file.path()
local_gravação <- "D:/MESTRADO/DADOS ILHABELA/DADOS ILHABELA/Trabalho CH - ilhabela presal/bases_orig_finbra_ilha"
leitura_arquivos_csv <- list.files(path = local_gravação, all.files = FALSE)

#
# Definindo agora um vetor com o nome dos arquivos 
# que vai excluir o diretório e a terminação "csv"
nomes_arquivos <- basename(leitura_arquivos_csv)
nomes_arquivos <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(nomes_arquivos)

for(i in seq_along(nomes_arquivos)){
  nome_arq <- file.path(local_gravação, nomes_arquivos[i])
  dados_tmp <- read_xlsx(nome_arq)
  assign(nomes_arquivos[i], dados_tmp)
}
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mas ainda há algo errado...

Comment: #Definindo um vetor com os nomes dos arquivos "leitura_arquivos"
leitura_arquivos <- list.files(path= "C:/Users/VAIO/Desktop/FINANCAS/Ilhabela", all.files = FALSE)
#
#Definindo agora um vetor com o nome dos arquivos "nomes_arquivos" que vai excluir a terminação "csv" 
#de todos eles;
nomes_arquivos <- substr(leitura_arquivos,8,21)

#####Fazendo o Loop com todos os arquivos########
#
#definido um string para a qtde de arquivos
quantidade_arq <-length(leitura_arquivos)

Comment: # Definir uma vez "local_gravação" e usá-la sempre 
# que for preciso. Não tem a barra final para mais
# tarde poder usar a função file.path()
local_gravação <- "C:/Users/VAIO/Desktop/FINANCAS/Ilhabela"
leitura_arquivos <- list.files(path = local_gravação, all.files = FALSE)
# fazendo o Loop "for i"
nomes_arquivos <- basename(leitura_arquivos)
nomes_arquivos <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(nomes_arquivos)

for(i in seq_along(nomes_arquivos)){nome_arq <- file.path(local_gravação, nomes_arquivos[i])
dados_tmp <- read_xlsx(nome_arq)
  assign(nomes_arquivos[i], dados_tmp)}

Comment: Está dando o seguinte erro:
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘C:/Users/VAIO/Desktop/FINANCAS/Ilhabela/finbra_municipios2013’

Comment: Rui Barradas, deu certo!!! Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @JoãoRicardoMorales O que fazer quando [alguém responde](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) às suas perguntas.